# BeautifulSoup find all image links on Imgur

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm unable to find all the links from Imgur albums.

Here's the html from imgur:

```
<div class="post-image">...
<a href="//i.imgur.com/P1VMco8.png" class="zoom"><img src="//i.imgur.com/P1VMco8.png" alt="" itemprop="contentURL" />
```

How do I extract only href from the page? I'm getting everything with below code.

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://imgur.com/a/OmD1E') as f:
    r = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
    result = soup.select(".post-image a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code prints all the image links:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://imgur.com/a/OmD1E') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'lxml')
for image in soup.select(".post-image"):
    print(image.a["href"])
```

If you're looking for only the first `.post-image` then do

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://imgur.com/a/OmD1E') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'lxml')
print(soup.select(".post-image")[0].a["href"])
```

Comment: thank you. a little modification and now i have a list of the image url